# Visual Studio taking long time to load solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I know that this is a trivial problem but Visual Studio 2008 has suddenly started taking a really long time to load one particular solution that I have. While watching the status bar it appears to get stuck on one project. That project is, however, the most trivial of all projects and is a simple library with a few DTO classes in it.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Installed any plugins recently?? After installing resharper VS is slow for me.

Comment: No plugins - I had resharper for a while on another machine but ended up uninstalling it. But not on the machine in question here.

Comment: Yeah, opening my visual studio 2008 solution takes up to 19 minutes.  Closing (even with no changes) takes equally as long.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a Setup project to the solution?  It seems to me that those take much longer to load than other types of projects.

Comment: Nope - no setup projects in this solution.